# Left join returning total records in SQL instead of matching records

Tags: mysql

I've written a Left join between two tables. My table structure is

```
SELECT  D.DLNOPK, D.STARTDT
FROM    DEALDETAILS D
LEFT JOIN 
            DEALCUSTOMERDETAILS P
ON      P.DLNO = D.DLNOPK
    WHERE P.CUSTOMERID = 'ABCD';
```

Actually the total number of rows in Deal details is 100, but even after writing the where clause, it returns 100 rows.

My table structure is

### DEALDETAILS

DLNOPK | STARTDT

### DEALCUSTOMERDETAILS

DLNO | CUSTOMERID

What is wrong with the where clause?

Comment: It's not `AND` but `WHERE` first then if you want more conditions you add a `AND`.

Comment: @FoxCy, can you plz let me know the exact  query

Comment: Try to exchange the Join like `ON D.DLNOPK = P.DLNO`

Comment: @FoxCy, if I want to fetch top 5 rows based on start date:?

Comment: In this case there is not enough information, it would be necessary to know where is stored the date for example.

Comment: Date format is yyyy-mm-dd in the database and I want to fetch only 5 rows .. I can use orderby for filtering based on date

Comment: swap position of table names in left join or use right join

Comment: @Anandhunadesh, please show the total query.

Comment: If you want only 5 rows then use the LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the total query you ask ^^

```html
SELECT  D.DLNOPK, D.STARTDT
FROM    DEALDETAILS D
LEFT JOIN   DEALCUSTOMERDETAILS P
ON    D.DLNOPK =  P.DLNO
WHERE P.CUSTOMERID = 'ABCD';
```

Comment: Here is my query . Please let me know if this needs changes.  SELECT  D.DLNOPK, D.STARTDT
FROM    DEALDETAILS D
LEFT JOIN   DEALCUSTOMERDETAILS P
ON    D.DLNOPK =  P.DLNO
WHERE P.CUSTOMERID = 'ABCD' ORDER BY D.STARTDTFETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY

Comment: Can you please check Anandhu response too. You have used left join and he has used right join. Which one is correct?

Comment: Thanks Foxcy. Accepting your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either `right join` or do `DEALCUSTOMERDETAILS left join DEALDETAILS`

Because your where condition is bound to `DEALCUSTOMERDETAILS` table.

```
SELECT  D.DLNOPK, D.STARTDT
FROM    DEALCUSTOMERDETAILS P 
LEFT JOIN 
DEALDETAILS D        
ON P.DLNO = D.DLNOPK
    WHERE P.CUSTOMERID = 'ABCD';
```

ELSE

```
 SELECT  D.DLNOPK, D.STARTDT
    FROM    DEALDETAILS D
    RIGHT JOIN 
     DEALCUSTOMERDETAILS P        
    ON P.DLNO = D.DLNOPK
        WHERE P.CUSTOMERID = 'ABCD';
```

Comment: Thanks Anandhu for your effort. I appreciate you.

Comment: @Yakhoob however swapping ON condition doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

It works well for me with this query

```
SELECT  D.DLNOPK, D.STARTDT
FROM    DEALDETAILS D
LEFT JOIN DEALCUSTOMERDETAILS P 
    ON P.DLNO = D.DLNOPK
WHERE P.CUSTOMERID = 'ABCD';
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfbc184/1)

Comment: Can you please check Foxcry response. The ON condition equal values are swapped. Which one is correct?

Comment: @Yakhoob swapping the `ON` condition has no effect on the result. Try it in the fiddle